# How is the convergent sequence $\frac{1}{n-1}$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

In a metric space all convergent sequences are bounded. This example in the real numbers should then be bounded but, it is infinite at n=1 so I do not understand how this can be true. In the proof commonly used for this theorem we use for a sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ that $d(x_n,x) < 1+\text{max}(d(x_1,x),d(x_2,x)...,d(x_N,x)))$ to get a bound but in this case then a maximum doesn't exist, is that right?

Comment: For $n = 1$ it's not defined.

Comment: In this case at $n=1$, $x_n$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $n=1$ term doesn't exist. Defining the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1} ^\infty$ by $x_n=1/(n-1)$ doesn't make sense. You can only define  $\{x_n\}_{n=2} ^\infty$, and then this is bounded.

Comment: I see, so in general you cannot define a sequence that includes some sort of singularity?

Comment: Yes. You are trying to form a real sequence, but $1/(1-1)$ is not in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Informally, I see analysis as a way of making the ideas of infinite and infinitesimal things rigorous. In general, when doing analysis like this you don't what things that are infinite already, since this isn't well-defined. You can have sequences of finite things tending to infinity, but never just infinity by itself. So if a sequence is unbounded then $|x_n| \to \infty$. It can never be that for some finite $n$, $x_n=\infty$ already.

Comment: I see, thanks .